# Wait until subtask is ready (celery + unittest)

Tags: python, django, celery, python-unittest

I have a task which called by parent task.

```
@shared_task
def task1():
    if condition:
        task2.apply_async()

@shared_task
def task2():
    pass
```

I want to test all flow starting by calling `task1` with unittest:

```
class NewTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_tasks(self):
        celery_task = task1.apply()
        celery_task.get()
        self.assertEqual(celery_task.state, "SUCCESS")
```

But in that case subtask `task2` goes into my local celery worker and executes there.
Is there any way to execute all task in test enviroment and wait until subtask is ready?
P.S.
`CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True` isn't a solution.
P.P.S
`CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True` is a solution. How silly. Thanks all.